# Using shadows in TikZ 3.0 graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have problems using the new graph drawing features in TikZ 3.0 with shadows.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{force}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw, circle, fill=white, circular drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{edge}=[draw,thick]

\begin{document}
\tikz
  \graph[spring layout, horizontal=a to b] {
    a[vertex] --[edge] b[vertex];
  };
\tikz
  \graph {
    a[vertex] --[edge] b[vertex];
  };
\end{document}
```

When using `spring layout` (I assume that this problem occurs with all layout algorithms) edges are behind the shadows. Without a layout algorithm the edges are above the shadows of vertices.

How can this be solved, so that edges are always above the shadow?

[image: Output]

Comment: Use the `nodes behind edges` option (p. 395, pgfmanual v3.0.0).

Comment: @PaulGaborit please convert your comment to an answer so we can move this to the answered realm. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the `nodes behind edges` option (p. 395, pgfmanual v3.0.0).

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{force}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw, circle, fill=white, circular drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{edge}=[draw,thick]
\begin{document}

\tikz \graph[nodes behind edges,spring layout, horizontal=a to b]
  { a[vertex] --[edge] b[vertex];};

\tikz \graph { a[vertex] --[edge] b[vertex]; };
\end{document}
```